# How do i edit my VBA Code from excel to include a specific line in the subject if conditions are met?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need to know how to automatically change my email subject line to a name in column A if corresponding column F-H equal approved or pending. I have 2 emails that are triggered based on cell Values Equal to approved and Pending, but i need the subject to contain the persons name "Column A" if F,G,OR H change

I posted my code below. any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
Sub Approved()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
strbody = "Team," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Approved. Update us when completed." & vbNewLine & _
"HR"

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Term Request: 1/1 Test Approved"
.body = strbody
.Display

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing

Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
strbody = "Team," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Term Request: 1/1 Test"
.body = strbody
.Display

 End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing

Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3:H14")) Is Nothing Then

    Select Case Target.Value

    'if Pending: Send term Email
        Case "Pending"
                Call CommandButton1_Click

    'If Approved: Send Approval Email
        Case "Approved"
                Call Approved
    End Select

    End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a loop through all the cells in `Target` because `Target` is not necessarily a single cell but can be a range of multiple cells and your code would fail on this.

You need to adjust your procedures (eg `Sub Approved`) so they take a parameter `PersonName` that is used for the subject:

```
Sub Approved(ByVal PersonName As String)
    'your code …

    .Subject = "Term Request: 1/1 Test for " & PersonName

    'your code …
End Sub
```

And finally you need to read the column A of the changed cell in your `Worksheet_Change` event and give it as parameter to your procedure `Approved PersonName:=Target.Parent.Cells(Cell.Row, "A")`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("F3:H14"))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange.Cells 'loop through all changed cells

            Select Case Cell.Value
                Case "Pending"  'if Pending: Send term Email
                    CommandButton1_Click PersonName:=Target.Parent.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value

                Case "Approved" 'If Approved: Send Approval Email
                    Approved PersonName:=Target.Parent.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value
            End Select

        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```